GET request of: org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.35/jersey-bom-2.35.pom from central failed
I don’t know how to solve it. Idea reported the following error:

org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:pom:2.35 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey:jersey-bom:pom:2.35 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.35/jersey-bom-2.35.pom from central failed
Try run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)




Please post data and code as plain text, NOT images.

The error suggests connectivity/networking issues, which Maven "caches" so it there was a problem of that kind that since has been resolved - check the corresponding folder in Maven Local and remove the files with lastUpdated extension.
